# How to Remove Flickering With Unity + Socket.io

Tags: node.js, unity-game-engine, socket.io

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivxzI.gif
```

[Question]

```
Hello, I am making a game using Unity and socket.io.
As a result of building on mobile, there is a stuttering phenomenon like the attached gif.
Is there a way to keep motion or reduce server delays?
```

[Server side code]

```
socket.on('updatePosition', (data) => {
player.position.x = data.position.x;
player.position.y = data.position.y;

    socket.broadcast.emit('updatePosition', player);
});
```

[Unity code for sending new position]

```
player.position.x = Mathf.Round(transform.position.x * 1000.0f) / 1000.0f;
player.position.y = Mathf.Round(transform.position.y * 1000.0f) / 1000.0f;
networkIdentity.GetSocket().Emit("updatePosition", new JSONObject(JsonUtility.ToJson(player)));
```

[Unity code for receiving new data]

```
string id = removeQuotes(E.data["id"].ToString());
float x = E.data["position"]["x"].f;
float y = E.data["position"]["y"].f;
NetworkIdentity ni = serverObjects[id];
ni.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
```

Comment: If the flickering you mean are the rather abrupt position changes of the character, considering [lerping](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.Lerp.html) the position updates. Some frameworks, like Photon, use additional semi-predictive positioning for even smoother effects.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
The goal is to implement it without using photons.
How can I predict location updates? Dead reckoning or ... Need a way

Comment: Photon's PUN2 prediction code is free on the asset store to look at, but just lerping would be a start to improve the smoothness.